# C# / Javascript What other ways to parse time from data

Tags: javascript, c#

I am working on a scraping logic to scrape https://www.bjs.com/product/lg-65uk6500aua-65%22-4k-uhd-hdr-smart-led-tv-with-white-glove-delivery/3000000000001274761.

I am after the Question and Answer section of the page. Apparently this page calls https://readservices-b2c.powerreviews.com/m/9794/l/en_US/product/P_169720/questions?sort=Newest&apikey=7c12e7e9-fe30-4e7a-bcb8-8376b9117a6b which returns json data.

I am trying to get the created date value for questions posted (root object > results > [0] > details > created_date).

The value that comes back for that field is 1534593729030.

I tried to parse it as ticks (C#) but the date seems off (January of year 0001).

The actual date on the page however is 2018-08-18T12:02:09.030Z or 5 months ago.

Do you guys have any idea how 1534593729030 ended up as 2018-08-18T12:02:09.030Z? Thanks.

Comment: That is a Epoch time (Unix time stamp) and not C# ticks. Look for epoch converter in C#. Using online converter I got "Saturday, August 18, 2018 12:02:09.030 PM" from 1534593729030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a version of Unix timestamp with milliseconds and the last 3 digits are milliseconds so

- 1534593729 -> this is Saturday, August 18, 2018 2:02:09.000 PM GMT+02:00 DST
- 1534593729030 -> so Saturday, August 18, 2018 2:02:09.030 PM GMT+02:00 DST

Check https://currentmillis.com/ for more information about

To convert is use:

```
    public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
    {
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a unix timestamp alright, it's just that it's the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 00:00:00. Divide by 1000 to get the unix time in seconds.

Just remember that you need to declare that number as a `long` due to the number of digits.